# Is there a method to set a value in rails to nil and save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

What I'm thinking of is something where I can say:

```
e = Foo.new
e.bar = "hello"
e.save
e.reload
e.bar.nil!
e.reload
e.bar.nil?  => true
```

Kind of #touch but sets nil and saves.

EDIT

Super sorry guys. I mean this:

```
e = Foo.new
e.bar = "hello"
e.save
e.reload
e.bar.nil!
e.reload
e.bar.nil?  => true
```

Comment: If `e` was `nil?` then `e.reload` would have raisen an error. Can you please clarify what you expect `nil!` (if it was existing) to do? Delete the record and nillify the current instance? Or destroy the record? Or just set some attribute (like `bar` in your question) to `nil`?

Comment: Do you mean you want to set `e.bar` to nil? If so, you can do `e.update(bar: nil)`. That will set the attribute and save all in one step.

Comment: What is the use case for it?

Comment: @shobhit ... nullifying something... I really like the "one shot" methods with ! on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
module ActiveRecord
  class Base
    def nil!(*names)
      unless persisted?
        raise ActiveRecordError, <<-MSG.squish
          cannot nil on a new or destroyed record object. Consider using
          persisted?, new_record?, or destroyed? before nilling
        MSG
      end

      unless names.empty?
        changes = {}

        names.each do |column|
          column = column.to_s
          changes[column] = write_attribute(column, nil)
        end

        primary_key = self.class.primary_key
        scope = self.class.unscoped.where(primary_key => _read_attribute(primary_key))

        if locking_enabled?
          locking_column = self.class.locking_column
          scope = scope.where(locking_column => _read_attribute(locking_column))
          changes[locking_column] = increment_lock
        end

        clear_attribute_changes(changes.keys)
        result = scope.update_all(changes) == 1

        if !result && locking_enabled?
          raise ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError.new(self, "nil")
        end

        @_trigger_update_callback = result
        result
      else
        true
      end      
    end
  end
end
```

Put that in an initializer and it'll let you null out the title of a comment with `Comment.last.nil!(:title)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't save a `nil` to the database, and furthermore, once an object has been created as a particular class you can never change that. It can only be converted by creating a new object, something an in-place modifier like this hypothetical `nil!` does.

The closest thing you can get is:

```
e = Foo.new
e.bar = "hello"
e.save
e.reload
e.delete!

e.reload
e.destroyed? # => true

f = Foo.find_by(id: e.id)
f.nil? # => true
```

Comment: I think you are missing my point. The Foo.new and etc.. is just to demonstrate we have an object with an value. The functionality I'm asking about is to nil out the value of that one specific attribute and save.

Comment: @apanzerj I'm basing this on your exact code, and in that code there is no attribute. If there was you'd be saying `e.bar = nil`.